# SQL JSON_TABLE query requires two tables to run the query

Tags: sql, json, oracle12c

I came across this situation when I ran this query , I get the error `json syntax error, the provided data has invalid syntax and could not be parsed`

```
    select D.*
  from J_PURCHASEORDER p,
       JSON_TABLE(
         p.PO_DOCUMENT ,
         '$' columns(PO_NUMBER    NUMBER(10)            path  '$.PONumber' ) ) D
 where PO_NUMBER between 450 and 455
```

however when i run the query

```
    select D.*
  from J_PURCHASEORDER p,O_OrderList l
       JSON_TABLE(
         p.PO_DOCUMENT ,
         '$' columns(PO_NUMBER    NUMBER(10)            path  '$.PONumber' ) ) D
 where PO_NUMBER between 450 and 455
```

the query seems to be running fine.
Can any one please help me out with this issue?

Comment: You're missing a comma after `O_OrderList l`.

Comment: Assuming that's a typo when you posted your question; does the second one run successfully and return all rows, or does it return some rows OK and then gets the same error later in the result set? You have a cartesian product between p and l so probably many more rows than you expected. The error suggests you have bad JSON in a p row; in the second query you might just not have reached that yet.

Comment: Please share sample data for which you are getting the error.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks. yes, there is a typo, The second one does run successfully. there are several thousands rows and i just realised, while i was scolling in the results in SQL developer i eventually got the same error. is there  a way i can avoid that ?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur For a limited set of data it seems to be working fine. but for a huge amount of unclustered data it fails.

Comment: @AsjadAzeez - you need to identify the row and `po_document` value that is not valid JSON. Then you either need to fix that data; or if it's legitimate for it to not be valid JSON (e.g. null) then define a rule to exclude that row from the query. Without knowing your data or seeing the value causing the issue, we can't advise how you should be handling it.

Comment: @AlexPoole sure trying it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the json syntax error using `where p.PO_DOCUMENT is json` in my query. that way, in case my column is not a json(due to any reason) it would skip it and now i am able to run the query without any issue.